# Dynamically Updating HTML src with Flask and Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a flask template that has a video like:

`<video id="firstVideo" class="clip-thumbnail" src=""></video>`

and upon an update from a user click, the request's videos content updates the video like:

`$('#firstVideo').attr("src", response['videos'][0]);`

but I want this to be dynamically updating on the page with something like:

`$('#firstVideo').attr("src", {{ url_for('static', filename='videos/' + response['videos'][0] ) }} )`

Is this the right way to handle this?  Will flask know to re-render the page after the update or do I need to re-render the page?

Comment: Just to be clear, their is one request for the page, you want to have the URL swapped in dynamically from somewhere hidden without making another request when the user clicks?

Comment: I want it to be swapped in dynamically from the output of a request.  So I have a REST API that returns the appropriate video url, and this get's swapped in.

Comment: then you can't use flask templating tags if you're doing an ajax request. the browser doesn't know how to interpret flask template tags.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use flask template tags unless you're building a dynamic template on your server, if you're making an ajax request for the video url from the browser you just need to set up your request to return the full video URL and then update the video src exactly as you have it:

```
$('#firstVideo').attr("src", response['videos'][0]);
```